# Monopoles in the fractual quantum Hall

Tags: magnetic-monopoles, quantum-hall-effect

What role do magnetic monopoles play in the fractional [quantum Hall effect](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/qhe.pdf)?

Also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect#Quantum_Hall_effect).

EDIT: I should add that I understand the fractual quantum Hall effect only from the perspective of minimal model CFTs, especially through the representations of their conformal blocks as Jack polynomials. The question is specific about monopoles because in some of my research a generalization of these polynomials occure as a basis of Verma modules for which a special type of string field is the highest weight state, which is connected to the equivariant cohomolgy of the instanton moduli space and I know that instantons can be understood as compositions of multiple monopoles.

Comment: Monopoles of what? Typically it is associated with U(1) gauge fields. You can ask about the monopole of the background U(1) gauge field, or the monopoles of the dynamical U(1) field in certain FQHs that can be described by U(1) Chern-Simons theories.

Comment: I think about monopoles in Yang-Mills theory where the gauge symmetry is brocken from $SU(N)$ to the Cartan subalgebra $U(1)^{N-1}$ by VEVs of the Higgs field, which are interpreted as the characters of the maximal torus of $SU(N)$.

Comment: That is not relevant to FQH.

Comment: Nice then I think I found a connection.